# Formalizing splitting into cases

Tags: logic, reference-request, propositional-calculus, type-theory

Let $x$ denote a fixed but arbitrary real, and suppose we're trying to solve an equation like $$(x^2-1)^2 = 1.$$

The 'high school' approach is to just shuffle the functions on one side onto the other side one at a time, by using the law $$f(x) = y \iff x = f^{-1}(y)$$

All well and good, but there's a problem: namely, that not all functions in sight are necessarily bijective. For instance, the self-map of the real line $x \mapsto x^2$ isn't bijective. To deal with this, the usual approach involves 'splitting into cases', like so:

[image]

So the "full-worked solution" the teacher is usually looking for is best understood as some kind of a tree.

The question then arises of what those lines actually *mean*, in a precise, technical sense. One possible semantics is that $$\frac{P}{Q_0,\cdots,Q_{n-1}} \iff \left(P \iff \mathop{\exists!}_{i \in \mathbb{N}_{<n}} Q_i\right)$$ where $P$ and the $Q_i$ are taken to be elements of the Boolean domain $\mathbb{B}$.

Another, different attempt at formalizing this kind of reasoning uses the [Iverson bracket.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket) We define $$\frac{P}{Q_0,\cdots,Q_{n-1}} \iff \left([P] = \sum_{i \in \mathbb{N}_{<n}} [Q_i]\right)$$

These approaches don't quite agree. For instance, consider the expression $$\frac{\mathrm{False}}{\mathrm{True} \quad \mathrm{True}}$$ Under the first definition, its true. Under the second definition, its false.

In any event, each approach gives us a way of assigning to each natural number $n \in \mathbb{N}$ a function $$\mathbb{B} \times \mathbb{B}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{B}$$

So we get a family of such functions.

> **Question 0.** Is there a consensus on which of these families is the 'correct' formalization?
>
> If so, what is this family of functions called, what are the main identities/laws it satisfies, and where can I learn more about it?
>
> Also, does anyone know of any formal proof calculi that describes how to reason with this thing?

I think we can go a lot further. If we agree to write $\sqcup$ for the coproduct of sets (also known as the "tagged union" or "discriminated union"), then the following inference rule looks very, very reasonable:

$$\frac{p:A \sqcup B}{p:A \qquad p:B}$$

This is different to what we were doing before, because now instead of dealing with booleans, we're dealing with typing judgements. Nonetheless, it seems to make sense.

> **Question 1.** Are there any type theories that take this kind of thing seriously?

Comment: *Proof by cases* is managed via [Disjunction elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction_elimination): you can "generalize" it to $n$ cases trivially, provided that they are exhaustive.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, yes, of course. But that deals with inclusive OR, which imo makes it different to the "problem solving by cases" we were all taught in high school. I suspect that inclusive OR is fundamentally the wrong way of thinking about this.

Comment: The inclusive OR does not preclude that the cases are non-overlapping. $Even(n) \lor Odd(n)$ is a perfectly correct way of using $\lor$ and well suited for proof by cases, exactly as $x=0 \lor x \ne 0$.

Answer (score 2):

This is usually formalized just as disjunctions. The initial split is by knowing that
$$ t^2=1 \to (t=1 \lor t=-1) $$
and the reasoning within each branch can then be done with metatheorems like
$$ (p\to q) \land (p\lor r) \to (q\lor r) $$

So I would say that your $\sqcup$ is simply the good old $\lor$. (In fact, for intuitionistic propositional logic, $\lor$ does correspond to tagged union under the Curry-Howard isomorphism).

Note that there's nothing in the form of the reasoning that depends on the cases being mutually exclusive -- they *happen to* conflict with each other, but there's nothing in the reasoning that uses this fact. The structure of the argument is exactly the same as when we split $ab=0$ into $a=0$ or $b=0$, in which the cases are *not* mutually exclusive.

We can also draw a parallel to classical *sequent calculus*, where we can derive
$$ t^2=1 \vdash t=1, t=-1 $$
because a comma on the right-hand side of the sequent is morally equivalent to a disjunction, and then work further on each of the cases "natively" within the calculus.